# ag-grid - Resize detail height when data changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I've got a table using a Master/Detail configuration and am using the `getRowHeight` callback.

The initial setting of height works as expected. My expectation is that when the table data is updated, the height for the rows containing a detail grid will be re-calculated but I cannot seem to trigger a resize of these.

My `getRowHeight` definition is:

```js
getRowHeight = params => params.node.detail ? this.getDetailHeight(params) : 48;

getDetailHeight = params => {
  let rows = params.data.filterData.length;
  return rows * 48 + 116; // all rows height + (header & footer)
};
```

The data for the table is updated as such (with the `deltaRowDataMode` flag being set):

```js
componentDidUpdate() {
    if (this && this.gridApi) {
      this.gridApi.setRowData(_.cloneDeep(this.props.data));
      this.gridApi.resetRowHeights();
      this.gridApi.forEachDetailGridInfo(detail => detail.api.resetRowHeights());
      this.gridApi.redrawRows(_.cloneDeep(this.props.data));
    }
  }
```

and I'd expect the call to `resetRowHeights` to trigger `getRowHeight` again, based on https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-row-height/#api-resetrowheights:

> ### `api.resetRowHeights()`
>
> Call this API to have the grid clear all the row heights and work them all out again from scratch - if you provide a getRowHeight() callback, it will be called again for each row. The grid will then resize and reposition all rows again. This is the shotgun approach.

However, the behaviour that I am seeing is `getRowHeight` being triggered for the master rows only and *not* the detail grid rows (not rows within the details table, but the height of the detail grid row itself).

I hope this is clear, thanks for any feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got something that works for my case, if anyone is ever having the same issue. I noticed that for detail nodes ag-grid would not clear the row height on `resetRowHeights` so I've updated my update method to handle this:

```js
componentDidUpdate() {
    if (this && this.gridApi) {
      this.gridApi.setRowData(_.cloneDeep(this.props.data));
      // call to resetRowHeights will apply the changes from forEachNode(..)
      this.gridApi.forEachNode(row => row.detailNode && row.detailNode.setRowHeight(null));
      this.gridApi.resetRowHeights();
      this.gridApi.redrawRows(_.cloneDeep(this.props.data));
    }
  }
```

This resets the rowHeight for the detail node so ag-grid reruns the `getRowHeight` call.

Comment: This issue has been raised with ag-grid as AG-2814

Comment: any change in this i try this code in v 22 not working. I have to change detail rows rows and getRowHeight only fire once not every detail render

Comment: @user2217288 According to [ag-grid's pipeline](https://www.ag-grid.com/ag-grid-pipeline/) this is still in their backlog to fix. Workaround above is still working for our application on ag-grid 23.0.2

Answer (score 0):

I've hooked into the `rowDataChanged` event (https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid/grid-events/#reference-miscellaneous) at which point I'm calling `this.gridApi.resetRowHeights();` - which only updates the heights when my data changes (rather than on resize, or redrawing the grid).

```
onRowDataChanged(params) {
  this.gridApi.resetRowHeights();
}
```